# How much of the total Ukrainian military budget comes from other countries?

Tags: ukraine, military, budget, foreign-aid

I am interested in how much of the total Ukrainian military budget comes from other countries seeing how much other countries are funding Ukraine in the war.

Comment: see also, but not a dupe, [How do Ukraine aid levels compare to what was being spent on Afghanistan?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/75191/how-do-ukraine-aid-levels-compare-to-what-was-being-spent-on-afghanistan)

Answer (score 9):

For a ballpark comparison, nominally Ukraine's defense budget was $44 billion in 2022, [according](https://www.sipri.org/news/2023/world-military-expenditure-reaches-new-record-high-european-spending-surges-0) to SIPRI. The  US alone sent [some](https://www.cfr.org/article/how-much-aid-has-us-sent-ukraine-here-are-six-charts) $46 billion in military and security assistance (not counting the other types of aid). Some further $26 billion were committed in financial aid. However, [according](https://www.ifw-kiel.de/topics/war-against-ukraine/ukraine-support-tracker/?cookieLevel=not-set) to IFW Kiel, only about half of the latter were actually disbursed. The EU has mostly sent the latter kind of (financial) aid, according to sources, but I'm wondering if there's not some accounting issue there, as o.m. discusses. Anyhow, IFW gives these in Euros: EU 19 billion military aid commitments; US 43 billion, UK 6.6 billion, Canada 1.4. Financial commitments: EU 35 billion, US 24 billion, UK 3 billion, Canada 2.

When making such comparisons, one also needs to account for the fact that at PPP Ukraine ([like Russia](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/50550/how-is-russia-able-to-maintain-the-2nd-most-powerful-military-in-the-world-at-a)) probably gets more bang from the buck when sourcing stuff internally [or from similar countries, say Bulgaria], but with many of Ukrainian factories in ruin (due to Russian long-range missiles), I'm not sure that's possible to quantify.

Comment: For what's worth it, based on IFW's numbers, [apparently](https://theprint.in/world/no-troops-on-ground-but-us-military-aid-to-ukraine-reaches-half-that-of-vietnam-war-german-study/1451479/) US still spent less per year on Ukraine than on either Korea, Iraq, or Vietnam wars, and about par with Afghanistan until 2010.

Comment: Also FWTW, North Vietnam received about 20-25% of its total budget from the Soviet block, between 1958-1962. I could not find later figures. For 1955-1959, on paper, the Chinese aid equalled the Vietnamese domestic budget, but there are some concerns the latter was overpriced by how the workers' contribution was valued. (We're talking entire budgets here, not just military.) https://www.jstor.org/stable/651476

Comment: This answere was more helpful then any answer I got from Quora.

Answer (score 8):

**Impossible to answer.**

At least impossible to answer the way you ask it.

- The Ukrainian government has a budget with income and expenditures. When a foreign entity gives money for a specific purpose like buying food or rebuilding a bridge, then Ukraine has to spend *less of their own money* on food or bridges, and they can spend *more of their own money* on the military.
  Ukraine is receiving [significant funding](https://www.ifw-kiel.de/topics/war-against-ukraine/ukraine-support-tracker/?cookieLevel=not-set) into their general budget as well as humanitarian and military aid.
- Ukraine is receiving military aid in the form of new or used material, not just money.
  In addition to the obvious public relations angle, the EU has created financial incentives for member countries to value their deliveries as high as possible since the community reimburses members for some expenses. Some countries valued 30-year-old military gear at €0, others [may have](https://www.politico.eu/article/eu-estonia-bumper-arms-reimbursement-ukraine-european-peace-facility/) used the original purchase price or even the current replacement purchase price.

Comment: The same fallacy is used all the time when governments create a new tax the revenues of which can only be used for one purpose, such as schools or the elderly or some other popular cause. In reality of course this is just a regular tax like any other as the government can now spend money from the general budget on something else. But voters are not smart enough to recognize this and vote for such taxes all the time.

Comment: @JonathanReez it imposes a floor on the spending on those things, which in some cases will be below what would have otherwise been spent, and in others will be above.

Comment: @Caleth from what I’ve seen the extra tax only covers a fraction of the current spending, so while it is indeed a floor, in reality the expenses on schools or parks or whatnot would never actually go down to such a low level. So it’s indeed a trick played on the voters though I’m sure there are some exceptions.